# Live update cell with next event in schedule in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a class schedule in google sheets and at the top I want to have a cell that displays the next event in the schedule. I think things like this can be done with VLOOKUP but I am not sure how to format all the cells so it can work. Ideally I would like it to be a range of cells that update to the time, topic and reading material for each event.

The schedule look like this:
[image]

What it might look like:
[image]

[Here is a link to a sample of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11z6lJ1DMcUsM-8hJUbynIZdoBrmKUflmc78tPFv8DnA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Lamma, can you clarify what the "next event event in the schedule" is, given your data/image?  Ideally you would share a sample sheet, indicating what exact result you want, and where, based on your sample data.

Comment: Hi Kirkg13, I am meaning given the current time and date what is the next event in the schedule so given then course has not started yet it would look something like what I have edited in the question. I have also added a sample sheet

Comment: Your sheet is not shared publicly, so we can't access it - please refer to this post, for how best to share.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: @kirkg13 Apologies, fixed now so you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if my solution in GK-Sheet1, added to your sample sheet, addresses your question.

This required two helper columns hidden in B and C, to get valid data and time values, since your date and time values in column D, (column B in your Sheet1) are text strings.  So I first extract valid dates and times from there.

```
=IFERROR(index(D2:G,
   IF(MATCH(J4+J5,C2:C,1)=(J4+J5),
      MATCH(J4+J5,C2:C,1)      +N("An exact time match"),
      MATCH(J4+J5,C2:C,1) +1   +N("In between time; need to look ahead to next session"))),
   {D3:G3})
```

Then, to test, I select a date and time value in cells J4 and J5.
The INDEX function in I7 then does a MATCH of the combined data and time from J4+J5, against the datetimes in hidden column C.

The only trick was handling the difference between an exact match, versus one where the current (test) time was in between session times, in which case we would want to return the next upconing session.

Lastly, there is one case that I haven't handled, and that is at the end of the day, or early in the day, where the next session will show as your Session Header for that half-day, like "Crash course in evolutionary biology and basic genomics" rather than the actual session at 9:15.

Further tests could be added to the INDEX function to correctly handle this, and skip ahead one row to the actual next session.

As a side note, I use the N("...") function to help document the formula. N("Any text") always equates to zero, so can be inserted anwhere you have a numeric value, such as adding to the result of the MATCH function.  Very useful.

[image]